# How do I find out what version of TinyMCE I am running?

Tags: tinymce

How do I find out what version of TinyMCE I am running?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Having a look at the source of tinymce (file `tiny_mce_src.js`, which is easier to read than, `tiny_mce.js` which is minified) :

```
var tinymce = {
    majorVersion : '3',
    minorVersion : '2.5',
    releaseDate : '2009-06-29',

    // lots of code ^^

})();
```

So, I'd say that, in Javascript, something like this :

```
tinymce.majorVersion + '.' + tinymce.minorVersion
```

would do.

I tried it on [the demo page](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php), using firebug, and I get :

```
>>> tinymce.majorVersion + '.' + tinymce.minorVersion
"3.2.5"
```

So, seems to be working ;-)

Comment: Neat that they include it for the client to check. Although, this results in ```"@@tinymce_major_version@@.@@tinymce_minor_version@@"``` if they're building from the source, in which cases, checking dates in companion files or their timestamps are your best option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

Open the page, on which you integrate the *tinyMCE* and press `Control+Shift+J`

and type following command.

```
tinyMCE
```

and the output of the above the command, will show both major version, minor version and release date as shown in figure.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

go to Chrome Console type tinyMCE.majorVersion and tinyMCE.minorVersion [take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjB1C.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you have included tinymce in your page, then you can view it in your browser dev-tool

```
tinymce
```

or

```
tinyMCE
```

and there will be visible *majorVersion* and *minorVersion* at first glance