# TinyMCE not working when loading two textareas

Tags: tinymce

I have two textareas that I load when the page loads, these two textareas are in the same table row. My tinyMCE looks like this

```
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "textareas",
                theme : "simple"
            });
```

For some odd reason only the first textarea gets assigned the editor and the second does not. Although it only does this in Firefox. The text areas have different names and don't contain ids. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give them different ids. Tinymce editor id is equal to the textareas id; if no textarea id is present "content" is used as default. In your case for both textareas. Because there is already a tinymce editor with id "content" when the second textarea is being converted into a tinymce editor instance - it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed by upgrading to the current version of tinyMCE (3.5b2) - as per:

http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/firefox-11-tinymce-issue-workaround-and-fix/

In my code, it was *not* fixed by giving different ids to the multiple text areas (Thariama's suggestion above).

If you don't know how to figure out your version of tinyMCE, see [How do I find out what version of TinyMCE I am running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284442/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-tinymce-i-am-running)

Comment: keep in mind that version 3.5b2 is still a beta version. i would not risk to use a beta version for my projects. it is better to wait till the new tinymce minor version is ready