# Wysiwyg mo editor for Drupal 5 forms (Form API): How to enable it for several textareas?

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg, form-api, drupal-5

I am trying to create a form with the Drupal 5 form API that has two textareas, both of which should have have a wysiwyg editor enabled to allow HTML formatted input. However, only the second textarea has the editor enabled, the other one displays the "Input format selector", but not the  editor controls.  I have tried  this with TinyMCE 3.3.9.3 and 3.3.9.4b and CKEditor 3.5.1.6398 both using the wysiwyg module integration, the result in both cases is  the same.

In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437340/tinymce-not-working-when-loading-two-textareas) it is mentioned that there might be a problem of identical IDs. I have no clue how to transfer this solution to the Drupal Form API, since I gave the two fields different names. In the generated HTML, they have separate HTML ids based on the Drupal names I assigned.

The code I used to create the text areas is the following:

```
$form['oos'] = array(
    '#tree' => false,
);

$form['oos']['oosmessage'] = array(
    '#description' => t('Something'),
    '#title' => t('Generic out of stock message'),
    '#type' => 'textarea',
);

$form['oos']['format'] = filter_form(1, 20, array('format'));

$form['oosmd'] = array(
    '#tree' => false,
);

$form['oosmd']['oosmessage_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Out of stock message until a specific date'),
    '#description' =>t('Something else.'),
);
$form['oosmd']['format'] = filter_form(1, 20, array('format'));
```

Thanks!

Ellen

Comment: Are there any javascript errors reported?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the two textareas different ids and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can tell, the two textareas already have different ids. Could you suggest what to change?

Comment: Hmm, i am not that much into Drupal myself. Could you please post what "tinymce.editors[0].id" and "tinymce.editors[1].id" yield when used int he firebug console?

Comment: They are both defined, but tinymce.editors is an empty array.

Comment: This is pretty wierd because the editorinstances are usually to be found inside tinymce.editors. which version are you using?

Comment: This is a beta release! I strongyl suggest you try the latest production release 3.3.9.3.

Comment: Thanks, I did. But it does not change anything.=

Comment: As I mentioned in my edit to the question,  I just tried substituting CKeditor for Tinymce and the result is the same.

Comment: hmm, i do not know how a replacement in drupal needs to be done