# How do I find out which TinyMCE version is installed in HCL Connections?

Tags: tinymce, ibm-connections, textboxio

HCL Connections has [some kind of customized build of TinyMCE](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v6/admin/install/c_inst_ephox_editor_overview.html), which could be officially used as replacement for the old CKEditor. I'd like to know which version is installed. Especially on test systems I'm not sure which version is currently installed on which system.

[Found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1284467/3276634) that this could be fetched from JS variables in the browser console:

```
tinymce.majorVersion + '.' + tinymce.minorVersion
"5.1.1"
```

But it misses the patch version 5.1.1-**XX** where XX is a number. Is there any other way how to find out detailled information about the installed version?

Answer (score 1):

There is a test page avaliable on the following url: https://cnx.host/connections/resources/web/tiny.editors.connections/verify.html

When TinyMCE was successfully installed (may require a restart of at least the common app), you'll see something like this:

> Tiny Editors for HCL Connections has been successfully installed. This
>   is release 4.1.0.15
>
> The TinyMCE version in this release is 5.1.1-57.
>
> The Textbox.io version in this release is 2.4.2.95.

This gave you four information:

1. The installation itself works. When enabled in `config.js`, you'll use TinyMCE instead of CKEditor in all Connections applications (Wikis, Blogs, ...)
2. The exact version numbers of TinyMCE = 5.1.1-57 (independent from Connection)
3. The Connections Editor version = 4.1.0.15 (HCL bundle of TinyMCE and Textbox.io editors)
4. The Textbox.io version = 2.4.2.95 (also independent from Connections, only relevant when using Textbox.io instead of TinyMCE)

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE version we ship for connections isn't a customised build; our customisations are all done through public APIs and configuration options (including the premium plugins).

If you see `5.1.1-57`, that should be an exact copy of the public `5.1.1` release available on our website. `57` is just an internal packaging build system number.

If you open the editor help dialog there should be version information there as well (but only the connections package version and current editor version, not both editor versions).

Answer (score 0):

The help dialog also contains the version of the editor and the integration. This is true for both textbox.io and TinyMCE and the steps are roughly the same. I show images for TinyMCE below.

First open the "cog" menu and click on the "Help" entry:
[image]

Second select the "Version" tab to view the version:
[image]